# Duplicated first tag during the video update by using YouTube API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am updating the category of a video by using the YouTube API v3, and apparently, I have to set the title, description, and also tags to avoid them resetting during the video update (this is another annoyance that I don't understand why the API doesn't simply use the existing values instead, but I am OK with that).

I update the video and retrieve the same video data by using the API and tags are all fine.

However, when I go to the YouTube Studio and open the same video in edit mode, then I see the first tag is duplicated!

Any ideas? I would normally trust the data that the API returns but YouTube Studio is not consistent with the API. In the worse case, if I have to leave it as is by considering that I'll be updating a lot of videos, is it a huge problem having a single tag duplicated?

### Update

In the Studio, I started to remove tags starting from the first tag which is duplicate, every remove click removed a tag from the list but the clicked "duplicate" tag stays intact. When I am done clicking on the remove icon on the "duplicate tag and deleting all other tags with this action, the chars limit at the bottom said 0/500 and the "duplicate" tag s still there.

I believe this should be an interface bug.

### Update 2

If I delete the duplicate "ghost" tag element from the document by using the browser developer tools, then everything works normally. I am now sure it is an interface bug, however, what I don't know is if it will affect the updated video for some reason. Normally, it shouldn't, because the API returns the correct data, however, what is normal I explained so far :) There must be a reason that Studio gets confused.

### Final Update

I am sure this whole thing is a side effect. When I update the category, which is the main reason for using the API and causing this tag issue, I can't update the subcategories like Academic System, because those fields are not exposed to API (I don't even think they are separate fields but hashes consist of multiple subcategory fields). Therefore, when I go to edit the same video in Studio, as soon as I click on the SHOW MORE button, the UNDO CHANGES button is enabled. That's because the Academic System that I was not able to set via API is auto-selected by the Studio script, therefore the form is dirty. During that action, the associated script must be doing something that is messing with the tags field that generates the duplicate "ghost" tag.

Regarding the possibility of an unwanted side-effect on the video record. No, and I can confirm this by looking at the HTML code of the video watch page and searching for the category that is correctly included as a meta element.

If there is a YouTube developer watching this channel, my question might help to identity/fix whatever is wrong. If that happens, I'd love to hear about it.